# Panels doesn't output views content pane title

Tags: views, theming, panels

I have a panel named **bar** in which I added a view-content-pane named **foo**.
For this view I created a *template-override named views-view--foo--panel-pane.tpl.php* in which I added, besides other things, a container for the $title like: `<div class="foo-heading"><div class="foo-title"><?php print $title; ?></div></div>`
The title of the view-content-pane is **Foo**.
To limit the moltiplication of *divs* I set to "No markup at all" the style of both the whole panel and the single pane.
Configured like that, the view shows with custom styles (which I setted in my custom theme-override) except for the title that doesn't display at all.
If I change the single pane style to "No style", the title is shown but using the panel default style (which breaks my layout).

It's there a way to output the view-content-pane title as configured in the template-override without this being rendered by the panel?

Comment: there is an option to disable panel page title.

Answer (score 2):

The `$title` variable for the `views_view` theme hook is added only for the administrative preview. Here is the section of code in `template_preprocess_views_view()` that adds the title: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views/tree/theme/theme.inc?h=7.x-3.11#n85

If you want to add that variable to your template override, you can do so with an additional preprocess.